# MsTest Run specific TestCase in Batch command in Jenkins

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, mstest

Hi I've a MsTest project configured in Jenkins.And Currently when I execute the test project using following batch command it'll run all the testcases in the project.

Assuming that I have a test case named **ABC** in my test project, How can I run only that specific test case in windows batch command in jenkins.

Here is the current command

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe"
 /testcontainer:"%WORKSPACE%\MYPROJECT\bin\debug\MYTEST.dll" 
/resultsfile:"%WORKSPACE%\result_%BUILD_NUMBER%.xml"
```

I tried this,but it didn't worked

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe"
     /testcontainer:"%WORKSPACE%\MYPROJECT\bin\debug\MYTEST.dll\test:ABC" 
    /resultsfile:"%WORKSPACE%\result_%BUILD_NUMBER%.xml"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing " and a space after `MYTEST.dll` and " `before ABC"`. Try this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe"
 /testcontainer:"%WORKSPACE%\MYPROJECT\bin\debug\MYTEST.dll" /test:"ABC" 
/resultsfile:"%WORKSPACE%\result_%BUILD_NUMBER%.xml"
```

Comment: I've mistaken in my question it was like this(I updated the question)
`/testcontainer:"%WORKSPACE%\MYPROJECT\bin\debug\MYTEST.dll\test:ABC" `

Comment: but even if I change it like yours still it executing all the testcases

Comment: Are you sure you've pasted exactly my code without typos? I've just tested it and it worked for me. Possibly your test case ABC is somwhere below in your test tree structure (like tests\something\somethingelse\ABC)? In this case you need the whole path inside the container tree.

Comment: Also this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825541/how-to-run-a-single-test-case-from-mstest

Comment: can you just give me an example

Comment: As stated in the linked question, you could try something like this: `mstest.exe /testcontainer:testproject.dll /test:TestNamespace.TestClass MethodTest1 /unique`